# Java.lang.Runtime, error trying start sqlite based android application

Tags: android, sqlite

I have a problem with an example I come up googling for android sqlite program, here is a source:

appTest.java

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.ContentValues;
import android.content.Context;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class appTest extends Activity {
    private static String[] FROM = { "ID", "TIME", "TITLE", };
    private static String ORDER_BY = "TIME DESC";

    private EventsData events;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
        events = new EventsData(this);
        try {
            addEvent("Hello, Android!");
            Cursor cursor = getEvents();
            showEvents(cursor);
        } finally {
            events.close();
        }
    }

    private void addEvent(String string) {
        SQLiteDatabase db = events.getWritableDatabase();
        ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
        values.put("titme", System.currentTimeMillis());
        values.put("title", string);
        db.insertOrThrow("event", null, values);
    }

    private Cursor getEvents() {
        SQLiteDatabase db = events.getReadableDatabase();
        Cursor cursor = db.query("event", FROM, null, null, null, null,ORDER_BY);
        startManagingCursor(cursor);
        return cursor;
    }

    private void showEvents(Cursor cursor) {
        StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder("Saved events:\n");
        while (cursor.moveToNext()) {
            long id = cursor.getLong(0);
            long time = cursor.getLong(1);
            String title = cursor.getString(2);
            builder.append(id).append(": ");
            builder.append(time).append(": ");
            builder.append(title).append("\n");
        }
        // Display on the screen
        TextView text = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.empty);
        text.setText(builder);
    } 
}

class EventsData extends SQLiteOpenHelper {
    private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "events.db";
    private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 1;

    /** Create a helper object for the Events database */
    public EventsData(Context ctx) {
        super(ctx, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
        db.execSQL("CREATE TABLE event (id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, time INTEGER,title TEXT NOT NULL);");
    }

    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
        db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS event");
        onCreate(db);
    }
}
```

main.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent">
    <!-- Note built-in ids for 'list' and 'empty' -->
    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/list"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/empty"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/empty" />
</LinearLayout>
```

string.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <string name="app_name">Events</string>
    <string name="empty">No events!</string>
</resources>
```

the error I receive is......:

```
java.lang.runtimeexception: unable to start activity componentInfo(test.o/test.o.appTest): android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: table event has no column named titme: while compiling: insert into event (title, titme) values (?,?);
```

any ideas?

ok I found this "titme" :), now I have blank screen [ with title of an app ]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

change `values.put("titme", System.currentTimeMillis());` to `values.put("time", System.currentTimeMillis());`

Comment: After creating cursor you should position it to the first record by `c.moveToFirst();` also instead of `while (c.moveToNext()) {}` use `do {} while (c.moveToNext())` or else you will always skip the first record.

Comment: I was under the impression that you can use the simple while loop as long as you don't call moveToFirst as well. If you do call moveToFirst then you need the do-while. Is this wrong?

Comment: @Craigy: yes, you are right. It's just a custom to be safe: l always call moveToFirst :)